# Not getting data from the firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I tried to fetch docs from the firestore, it returns an empty array but when I run console.log(docs); outside the declared function, it returns the actual array. I know this error occurs because my useEffect function runs first before getting the docs from the firestore.
I want to know how to fix this issue.

```
const Component = (props) => {
    const { docs } = useFirestore('books');
    const id = props.match.params.id;
    
    const loadContent = () => {
        const book = docs && docs.filter(doc => doc.id === id);
        console.log(book); //not getting book from the docs because docs is empty
    }
    
    useEffect(() => {
        async function getContent(){
            await loadContent();
        }
        getContent()
    },[]);
};
```

useFirestore.js

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { firestore } from '../config/fbConfig';

const useFirestore = (collection) => {
    const [docs, setDocs] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    // getting realtime data from the firebase for books
    useEffect(() => {
        let unsubscribe = firestore.collection(collection)
        // .orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
        .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
          const items = [];
          querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            items.push({...doc.data(), id: doc.id});
          });
          setDocs(items);
          setLoading(false);
        });
        return unsubscribe;
      }, []); // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  
    return { docs, loading };
}

export default useFirestore;
```

Comment: Is useFirestore a custom code or from any library?

Comment: expanding on @farvilain 's comment - this is not at all typical Firestore code - other than the word "useFirestore" (which I *guess* is some sort of custom hook?), none of the rest looks like any typical Firestore code.

Comment: useFirestore is a custom hook that takes collection as an argument and then get data and return the doc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are pretty close to getting the expected behaviour. Here's how I'd approach it:

```
const Component = props => {
  const { docs } = useFirestore("books");

  const id = props.match.params.id;

  // useMemo - whenever `docs` change, recalculate the book variable.
  // If `docs` don't change, `book` will also not change.
  // Your `docs` will probably change on every snapshot.
  const book = useMemo(() => docs && docs.filter(doc => doc.id === id), [docs]);

  console.log(book);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (book) {
      // Do something with the book, e.g. loadContent(book).
      // Keep in mind that this will run on every snapshot.
      // If you only want to run this once, you'll need an
      // extra state variable to store that the effect was
      // already run, and check it here.
    }
  }, [book]); // The effect will run whenever book changes
};
```

The `useFirestore` hook looks almost fine, only one remark: right now even if you change the `collection` parameter, the snapshot listener won't change. You might want to do this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = firestore.collection(collection).onSnapshot(snapshot => {
    const items = snapshot.map(doc => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id }));
    setDocs(items);
    setLoading(false);
  });

  return unsubscribe;

  // Whenever `collection` changes, `unsubscribe` will be called, and then this hook
  // will subscribe to the new collection.
}, [collection]);
```

### Upd.

If you want the `useFirestore` hook to only query for a particular book, you need to change the hook to accept and use a document ID, something like this:

```
const getDoc = doc => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id });

const useFirestore = (collection, docId) => {
  const [docs, setDocs] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    let subject = firestore.collection(collection);

    if (docId) {
      // If docId is available, listen for changes to a
      // particular document
      subject = subject.doc(docId);
    }

    const unsubscribe = subject.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
      // Notice here that if listening for a particular docId,
      // the snapshot will be that document, not an array.
      // To maintain the interface of the hook, I convert that
      // document to an array with a single item.
      const items = docId ? [getDoc(doc)] : snapshot.map(getDoc);
      setDocs(items);
      setLoading(false);
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, [collection, docId]);

  return { docs, loading };
};
```

Comment: Hello Avius, I want to know If I call useFirestore hook and only want 1 particular book(like in particular book details and edit book details component) but useFirestore hook return all the books docs, this will cost me more reads. How should I avoid that?

Comment: You need to listen for snapshots of a particular document. See update.

Answer (score 1):

I need more informations on the 'useFirestore' code but you should at least write your code like that.

- do not list every document on firestore to just get one (you pay for each read request)
- load the document in useEffect, not outside
- useEffect must depend on the id

  ```
     const Component = (props) => {
         const id = props.match.params.id;
         const firestore = //;
         const [book, bookSet] = useState(false);

         useEffect(() => {
             //Depending on useFirestore code
             firestore.collections('books').doc(id)
             .then( snapshot => {
                 if ( !snapshot.exists ) {
                     bookSet(null);
                 } else {
                     bookSet(snapshot.data());
                 }
             });
         }, [id]);

         if( book === false) return <p>Loading</p>
         if (!book) return <p>Not exists</p>
         return <p>Display it</p>;
     };
  ```

**Edition**

Here is my guess with your 'useFirestore' hooks

```
  const Component = (props) => {
      const id = props.match.params.id;
      const { docs, loading } = useFirestore('books');
      
      useEffect(() => {
          if( loading) console.log('Loading');
          return;

          const book = docs && docs.filter(doc => doc.id === id);
          console.log({book});
      },[loading, docs, id]);
  };
```

Comment: Hello farvilain, Thanks for your response, I added a useFirestore code. please take a look and suggest to me some way to get docs array. My purpose is to filter particular book and then put the book detail in the edit form and then update the book detail. The problem is getting that particular book data. Please help me with this issue.

Comment: I'm not a react expert but I think this is not the way to write a hook. So I'll update my post to reflect your useFirestore... but again, it seems to me wrong. Perhaps you should considere calling Firestore directly inside component or use some existing react-firestore libraries

Comment: Nope I can't make it works, I will provide you another method but not be able to use this useFirestore. Could you accept to stop using it?